# Sampling unsigned integers from Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl, glsles

I am trying to load a 1D texture of unsigned integers to the shader. Each element of the texture can only be 1 or 0 (I need to do this), and that value depends on the choice the user does in the UI of my app. I am absolutely stuck on this apparently easy issue, I cannot get what I am doing wrong.
This is my OpenGL code:

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_inside_texture_id);
vtkgl::ActiveTexture(vtkgl::TEXTURE16); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_inside_texture_id); 

glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D,0,vtkgl::R8UI,insideVector.size(),
        0,vtkgl::R8UI,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &insideVector[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_inside_texture_id);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, vtkgl::CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
```

And this is the GLSL code I am using to fetch that texture:

```
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable

uniform usampler1D insideVector;

uint inside2 = texture1D(insideVector, indexInVector).a;

if (inside2 == 0)
{
    gl_FragColor = shade(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
}
else if (inside2 == 1)
{
    gl_FragColor = shade(vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
}
```

insideVector is a vector of GLubytes. 
indexInVector is a normalized unsigned integer which grows each time the user changes is choice (each time: insideVector.push_back(1) or insideVector.push_back(0) and indexInVector=insideVector.size()- (1/255))

It compiles, but crashes when trying to use the inside2 variable.
The OpenGL version I am using is 2.1 with lot of extensions.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The uniform var insideVector is set as follow:

```
vtkUniformVariables *v;
ivalue = 16;
v->SetUniformi("insideVector", 1, &ivalue);
```

**SOLVED**
The issue was in the shader. inside2 is an unsigned integer, so it must be compared to unsigned integers (0u and 1u) instead of signed integers (0 and 1).

Comment: 1. This is not C++ question. Remove the tag.
2. I dont see any code where you are setting the uniform var in to shader. You have to set the texture as uniform. Write full code.

Comment: Hi @PankajBansal , I had the same code running with unsigned normalized data type instead of unsigned integers, so I guess the problem is just about working with unsigned integers.

Comment: @PankajBansal: It sure looks like a C++ question to me. It's obviously not Java or C# because it uses the address-of operator and it's not C because it's using namespaces. Language tags are very important in OpenGL questions because each language has its own bindings; stuff in the C and C++ bindings that uses pointers may have completely different function signatures in Java or C# for their lack of pointer data types.

Comment: @pedroddm: Why do you need an integer texture at all if your only possible values are **0** and **1**? A traditional unsigned normalized texture (e.g. `GL_R8`) can _precisely_ represent both **0.0** and **1.0** and you can just cast that to an integer without introducing any extension dependencies.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I need to load a much more complicated texture in my app now, and I want to do that with unsigned integers. I tried to make that work with a more simple texture first like the one in this example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Integer textures are possible, see isamplers and usamplers, you can actually sample the integer and unsigned integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Likely unrelated to the crash but "R" in "R8UI" means red, so in your shader you should replace

```
uint inside2 = texture1D(insideVector, indexInVector).a;
```

with

```
uint inside2 = texture1D(insideVector, indexInVector).r;
```

also, the glTexImage1D call seems wrong: the format parameter should be GL_RED_INTEGER; GL_R8UI is for internal format.

Comment: The correct format parameter in this case is `GL_RED_INTEGER`, not `GL_RED`.